# How to fix the geom_col(width = 1) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I struggled to fit the geom_col(width = 1) in ggplot2.

Here are my codes:

```html
df <- data.frame(Y = c(0.45, 0.25,  0.05, -0.05, -0.25, -0.45),
                 X = rep(9, n = 6))
df
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(Y %in% c(-0.45, 0.45, -0.25, 0.25) ~ '#6BD7AF',
                           TRUE ~ 'grey')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = factor(Y), fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = c('#6BD7AF' = '#6BD7AF', 'grey' = 'grey'),
                    labels = c('Incorrect', 'Correct')) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = 'y', x = ' x') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, xlim = c(1, NA)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 9, by = 1))+
  scale_y_discrete(labels = seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.2))
```

I want to fit the grey area in my diagram exactly between -0.1 and +0.1. The codes work perfectly, but not sure why the grey does not fit between -0.1 and +0.1. I also want to use density and angle for the green colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a discrete scale, and the centre of bars will always be at the tick marks, so this probably isn't the way to go. A `geom_rect` would make more sense here. For density and angle fills, you will need `ggpattern`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

df <- data.frame(xmin = rep(0, 3), xmax = rep(9, 3), 
                 ymin = c(-Inf, -0.1, 0.1), ymax = c(-0.1, 0.1, Inf),
                 fill = c("Incorrect", "Correct", "Incorrect"))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect_pattern(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                pattern = fill, pattern_fill = fill, fill = fill),
                pattern_colour = NA, pattern_angle = 45,
                pattern_density = 0.3, pattern_spacing = 0.02) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = 'y', x = ' x') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, xlim = c(1, NA)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 9, by = 1), limits = c(0, 9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 0.5), breaks = seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.2)) +
  scale_pattern_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("gray", '#6BD7AF')) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("gray", "white")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(NULL, values = c("none", "stripe"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Allan. In case that I want to have a pattern for the grey. I mean if I want to have a pattern for the grey and no pattern for the Green, can we do it?

Comment: @user330 yes, just swap the "none" and "stripe" in the last line and change `c("gray", "white")` in the second-last line to `c("white",  '#6BD7AF')`